# Swap position of two iterators in container

Tags: c++, stl

I want to swap position of two iterators `first` and `second` in container and also keep them valid after operation. Moreover if I have iterator `other` pointing at the same value as `first` I want to keep it valid too (keep it pointing at the same value). Is it possible to achieve with any STL container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::list` allows you to splice a piece of one list into another (removing it from the first list) without invalidating any iterators, references or pointers, and the source list and destination list can be the same object.

(This is according to the draft C++11 standard; I don't know if the C++03 standard says the same thing.)

Comment: I haven't noticed this method, I'll check it :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried swapping them?

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...

swap(first, second);
```

(In C++0x, it is sufficient to `#include` the significantly smaller header `<utility>`.)

> Moreover if I have iterator `other` pointing at the same value as `first` I want to keep it valid too (keep it pointing at the same value).

Just reassign `other` after swapping:

```
swap(first, second);
other = first;
```

Comment: I've updated the question. I need something like ordered queue based on individual counter connected with all elements. When counter is decreased element is moved down the queue.

Comment: Closer, but it's still not the solution. I don't know all iterators pointing to the same value, so I'm looking for something what will work behind the scene and affect all iterators.

Comment: @Goofy: Sounds like you need [one more level of indirection](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OneMoreLevelOfIndirection)... you could write an iterator wrapper that wraps a normal iterator but provides methods to "re-bind" them, and then use iterator wrappers instead of normal iterators in your normal code.

Comment: @Goofy: not sure if it helps but take a look at std::priority_queue http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/